# Image file within state becoming "f.i.l.e.D.a.t.a.0" when checking

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, input

I'm having a problem where images that get set to state somehow turn into "f.i.l.e.D.a.t.a.0" and I'm not sure how this is happening.

I first have an input set to the type of file within my form as

```
<input multiple={true} type="file" placeholder="Upload Image" onChange={handleUploadImage} />
```

This allows for a person to select and image and upload it. When an image gets uploaded, we save it to an array of images through the onChange as

```
const handleUploadImage = ({ target }) => {
    const file = [ target.files[0] ];
    const url = window.URL.createObjectURL(target.files[0]);

    setImage(images.concat(file));
    setImagesUrl(imagesUrl.concat([ url ]));
};
```

The reason for the `createObjectURL` is because we want to be able to pass this collection of URL to a component which roll is just to display all the images. At this point the image, has an object and it hasn't turned into"f.i.l.e.D.a.t.a.0"`

When I upload images one after another. The states look like

```
checking what images look like:  (2) [File, File]0: File {name: "Screen Shot 2019-11-21 at 6.48.40 AM.png", lastModified: 1574336926040, lastModifiedDate: Thu Nov 21 2019 06:48:46 GMT-0500 (Eastern Standard Time), webkitRelativePath: "", size: 25786, …}1: File {name: "Screen Shot 2019-11-21 at 6.58.34 AM.png", lastModified: 1574337520016, lastModifiedDate: Thu Nov 21 2019 06:58:40 GMT-0500 (Eastern Standard Time), webkitRelativePath: "", size: 166495, …}length: 2__proto__: Array(0)
create-new-product.js:85 this is the images url:  (2) ["blob:http://localhost:3000/18df975a-a19e-4761-900c-7e7d928960d7", "blob:http://localhost:3000/64853ca3-19a3-499d-8ad9-5b85b2698c2a"]
```

So far there hasn't been any changes except when I click on the `handleRemove` function. When I click on it the result we get in return is

```
checking what images look like:  (2) ["f.i.l.e.D.a.t.a.0", "f.i.l.e.D.a.t.a.1"]
```

While the URL does not change. Within my `handleRemove` function I'll I'm doing is

```
const handleRemove = (e) => {
    console.log(e);
    console.log(images);
    // const newImages = image.filter((image) => image.name === name);
    // setImage(newImages);
};
```

Is there something I'm doing wrong that is somehow converting these into a string? I know this happens when I upload them to the backend with graphql but I'm not sure why this is happening. Since I won't be able to remove a specific file based on name as the object disappears.

Thank you for all the help on this one.

UPDATE

Another thing I noticed was when i click on the x to remove an image. It is somehow also submitting the form causing possibly the ``"f.i.l.e.D.a.t.a.0"`to occur since when I removed`fileData` as a property, it's asking for it from the GraphQL which shouldnt as I'm not clicking submit. My x button looks like this

```
        <div>
            <img src={imageCollection} />
            <button onClick={() => handleRemove(imageCollection)}>X</button>
        </div>
```